# Sync local repository with branch of remote repository

Tags: git, github, repository, git-remote

I have a local repository where some of the files are different from that of the remote branch repository.
I haven't initialized and synced this repository so I want to make that repository to point out to the branch of my remote repo without adding any local changes to the remote.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use `git pull <branch>`?

Comment: git reset --hard origin/<branch name> ?